# How can I make TextView visible for a few seconds and then hide it, in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, hide, visible

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        if (editText.text.isNotEmpty()) {
            when (editText.text.toString().toInt()) {
                1 -> {
                    textView.text = "Ваш ручной выбор: Понедельник"
                }
                2 -> {
                    textView.text = "Ваш ручной выбор: Вторник"
                }
                3 -> {
                    textView.text = "Ваш ручной выбор: Среда"
                }
                4 -> {
                    textView.text = "Ваш ручной выбор: Четверг"
                }
                5 -> {
                    textView.text = "Ваш ручной выбор: Пятница"
                }
                6 -> {
                    textView.text = "Ваш ручной выбор: Суббота"
                }
                7 -> {
                    textView.text = "Ваш ручной выбор: Воскресенье"
                }
                else -> {
                    textView.text = "Такой день недели нет"
                }
            }
```

must work with "when" choice
and repeat visibility and invisibility again when numbers changes

I tried  alphaAnim but it works only once (in my Fragment)...

added:
for example this code, I wanna hide textView after 3 seconds and when it will get new numbers repeat that, I mean show again textView and hide again

```
open class Begin1Fragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
        private lateinit var button: Button
        private lateinit var editText: EditText
        private lateinit var textView: TextView
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_begin1, container, false)
    
            editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextBegin1)
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewBegin1)
            button = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonBegin1)
            view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonBegin1).setOnClickListener(this)
            return view
    
        }
    
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            when {
                editText.text.isNotEmpty() -> {
                    val a = editText.text.toString().toInt()
                    if (a < 0 || a == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Периметр квадрата не может быть отрицательным или нулевым", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }else if (a > 0) {
                        val p = 4 * a
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Периметр квадрата равен: $p", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        textView.text = "Периметр квадрата равен: $p"
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
                editText.text.isEmpty() -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Введите данные", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                else -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Ошибка!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `alphaAnim` is an appropriate solution. Please show your code for that so we can tell you what's missing from it.

Comment: I removed my alphaAnim code cuz I wanted build

Comment: @Tenfour04 check that sir